# How can alpha or beta emission maintain equal numbers of protons and electrons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, subatomic

In radioactivity we know that a parent nucleus can disintegrate into daughter nuclei by emitting alpha or beta particles. If this is true then how can the daughter nucleus have as many electrons as protons?

For example, suppose a parent nucleus emits an alpha particle. Its mass number gets decreased by 4 and its atomic number gets decreased by 2 as it converts into a daughter nucleus. Now, how can the number of electrons and protons be the same?

Comment: Who told you that the daughter has the same $Z$ as the parent in alpha or beta decay? It doesn't. Perhaps you are confusing something that you heard about gamma decays with properties of different decays.

Comment: And alpha particles don't have 4 protons.

Comment: I'm not saying that parent and daughter nuclei have same Z. I'm saying that after decay, how the number of protons and electrons will be same(in daughter)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a *nucleus* has no electrons at all. The number of protons ($Z$) was never the same as the number of electrons (zero).

Of course, most nuclei are part of complete atoms. If a nucleus that is part of an atom decays by alpha emission, it will typically also lose two electrons. That's not usually mentioned because it's not part of the radioactive decay process; it happens afterwards. The two electrons might attach themselves to the alpha particle to form a helium atom, or they could just be kicked out into free space, or they could take advantage of any other way for electrons to be shuttled away from the daughter atom.

Alternatively, it is also *possible* that one or both of the electrons stick around and you wind up with a negatively charged ion.

When an atom's nucleus decays by beta emission, typically the emitted beta particle (electron) will be captured into an orbital. It could also be emitted away leaving a positively charged ion.